# How does transitive dependencies for Microsoft.NETCore.App and Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms work

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a really hard time figuring out how version resolving of transitive dependencies works for the framework "metapackages".

The reason I am asking is that it seems to be each time we pull in an "old" dependency, for instance something that points to `netstandard2.0` or 2.1 we end up with a long list of outdated packages (which again is reported by our build pipeline).

As an example:

Given a .net6 class library, created like this:

```
dotnet new classlib
dotnet add pakage System.Data.SqlClient
```

The resulting csproj looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

That seems like its fine. I have the latest SqlClient and im on .net6 \o/

Now when i execute `dotnet list package --outdated --include-transitive`

I get the following output:

```
Project `Outdated` has the following updates to its packages
   [net6.0]:
   Transitive Package                       Resolved   Latest
   > Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms            3.1.0      6.0.3
   > Microsoft.Win32.Registry               4.7.0      5.0.0
   > System.Security.AccessControl          4.7.0      6.0.0
   > System.Security.Principal.Windows      4.7.0      5.0.0
```

As far as I can tell `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is part of the "shared framework" and would have expected it to use the latest version.

Can anyone explain why it does not use the latest version?
Alternatively how I can force dotnet to use the latest version without a direct dependency (if its possible - again i am trying to avoid a LONG list of outdated transient dependencies that exists in the shared framework...).

Comment: This tool will help updating dependencies, you may need to run more than once to upgrade to latest version
dotnet outdated -t -u
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/your-dotnet-outdated-is-outdated-update-and-help-keep-your-net-projects-up-to-date

Comment: Yes I know about dotnet outdated, but it still does not help me understand whats going on.

Comment: A side note: `dotnet outdated` will end up with "a LONG list of outdated transient dependencies that exists in the shared framework"

Answer (score 3):

Going through various NuGet/dotnet Github issues and discussions.
It seems like the way NuGet restores dependencies is to blame. It defaults to the lowest version satisfying all requirements.

The "meta" packages are in fact not tied to the SDK version but have direct dependencies on other packages, such as the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` which targets `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` as version `2.2.4` or higher.

Since `System.Data.SqlClient` is a .NET Core 3.1 package, it refers `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` version `3.1.0` (or higher).

Since my project does not have a direct dependency on `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` well, NuGet chooses the lowest one.

I still really do not understand why the SDK reference does not cause a direct dependency, but I guess that reasoning have drowned in some GitHub issue discussion.

The following contains a description of the resolution strategy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-rules

Long story short - Its currently only possible to get the latest versions with a long list of specific dependencies.

**Edit**

Maybe a variation is using Central Package Management: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-central-package-management/