# Transitive dependency `microsoft.netcore.platforms 5.0.0` for EF Core SqlServer package

Tags: resharper

Checking my CSPROJ file, I noticed a warning (blue squirly) on this package.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.4" />
```

The error points out *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* as the culprit and mentions the floowing.

> Transitive dependency microsoft.netcore.platforms 5.0.0 contains vulnerabilities according to checkmarx(c).

I've never noticed that before and googling it produced rather little ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493623/how-does-transitive-dependencies-for-microsoft-netcore-app-and-microsoft-netcore), not really addressing it, and [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-490845/SWEA-Transitive-dependency-Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms-5.0.0-contains-vulnerabilities-according-to-Checkmarx-warning-persists), not really answering the question, as far my undertstanding goes).

How can I kill the warning?

When I selected the suggested change, a new line appeared in the CSPROJ file, like this.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" Version="7.0.1" />
```

However, the blur squirly warning keeps showing still. I'm confused.

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  Clean build will recompile all source files into obj files.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I have cleaned it and built again. Both with and without the second packages reference. Same behavior remains. It drives me nuts because it doesn't seem to affect or impair my software so I have hard time motivating a huge effort investigating it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm asuming you use ReSharper? Because underlining vulnerable packages in a `.csproj`-file is a feature of ReSharper.

You can disable this warning once with a comment:

```xml
<!-- ReSharper disable once VulnerablePackage -->
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.4" />
```

If you do not want to use the vulnerability detection feature at all go to `Extensions > ReSharper > Options > Environment > Products & Features > Uncheck: Package Checker`.

Comment: I am using Resharper, yes. However, what I'm looking for is not getting rid of the blue squirlies. I'm looking for a way to resolve the (alleged?) vulnerability in the most proper way. Also, trying to understand why the suggested solution didn't helped.

Comment: The last comment [in your linked issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-490845/SWEA-Transitive-dependency-Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms-5.0.0-contains-vulnerabilities-according-to-Checkmarx-warning-persists#focus=Comments-27-6813954.0-0) says: _...Transitive dependency checking does not appear to compare against current Package References_. This implies that is there is bug in ReSharper that still reports vulnerabilities even if a newer package that resolves the vulnerability is referenced. However, it appears that this bug is fixed in 2023.1 EAP 7. Tried updating to 2023.1?

Comment: That would be the anti-climax of the month... I simply refuse to accept your reality and substitute it for something pink and fluffy.   :)

Comment: There's been extremely little activity on this topic. I guess this is as far we'll get. You'll be bountied. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity: Did updating to 2023.1 resolve the issue?

Comment: Hey there! I didn't notice the newest version of R#. Guess what, the warning is gone now. I can sleep well tonight knowing that everything works just as before with a slight improvement of warning rendition in a file nobody's visiting. Yey!   :)